# What does this convoluted regex line do in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I've a C++11 file using regex that I'm converting to a C++98 file. In the file, I've this line that does some manipulation that I don't understand.

`regex separator_regex(R"((([[:alpha:]]:[^:;]*)|([^:;]*))([:;]|$))");`.

If I'm correct, `seperator_regex` is a regex class, and R is used as a raw string literal so the code doesn't exit out. However, what is the rest of the snippet trying to do?

Comment: The rest of the code is a regular expression.

Comment: Yes, my question is what does it mean? What is it trying to do?

Comment: I don't envy you at all, C++11 has a lot of good stuff that's missing in C++98. And regular expressions are much harder to read than they are to write.

Comment: Have you tried reading a regexp tutorial, such as www.regular-expression.info?

Comment: You can also paste the regexp into regex101.com. It will show a description of what each piece means.

Comment: Regular expressions are a good example of write-only languages.

Comment: If the linked question doesn't answer your question ((it lists the languages it covers, and C++ isn't one of them - OTOH, this is all pretty basic), @mention me, and I will reopen it.

Comment: Your options are: 1. Use Boost Regexp.  2.  Rewrite the parser by hand.  3.  Rewrite using (eg) flex/bison.  4.  Decide that all the previous are too expensive, and (biting the bullet) upgrade to C++11.

Comment: @MartinBonner I still couldn't figure it out, I'd a look over the internet, although I guess I`m fairly new to programming.

Comment: @MartinBonner unfortunately, I'm going to have to go with the second option and rewrite this by hand, which is why I wanted to understand it first.

Comment: So why doesn't the linked duplicate cover your question?

Comment: I honestly still don't understand the answer to my question

Comment: I can't answer since it's been marked as duplicate unfortunately. Did something like regex101.com not solve explain it well enough?

Comment: It is a dupe of "What does this regex mean" because all you need to understand a simple regex like this is there. There are tons of links to online regex debuggers. See [your pattern explanation and demo](https://regex101.com/r/szSyRA/1). It the same as [this one without capturing groups](https://regex101.com/r/szSyRA/3).